# How do you take a partial derivative symbolically in sympy while holding a parameter constant/having a fixed parameter?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I am trying to get a partial derivative in the form seen [here on page 2 in equation 6.1](https://www2.atmos.umd.edu/%7Eekalnay/syllabi/AOSC614/ch2-6-VerticalCoords.pdf). The meaning of the subscripts in this equation is that one of parameters that the variable having a derivative taken of it depends on is being held constant. Is there any argument in the Derivative() function in Sympy that allows one to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
from sympy import*
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
#Create the variables
s = symbols('s') #x, y, and t
z = symbols('z') #vertical coordinate

#Create the functions that depend on those variables
zeta = Function('zeta')(s,z)
A = Function('A')(s,zeta)

#Here we actually take the derivative
expr = Derivative(A,z)
expr = expr.doit()
#This gives a basic partial derivative, but does not give a partial derivative with one of the parameters held constant
```

Is there some type of kwargs that I can pass into Derivative function that allows for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to represent a derivative wrt the "nth argument" in sympy but you can use a dummy variable and subs. Something like:

```
In [24]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [25]: A = Function('A')

In [26]: f = Function('f')

In [27]: A(x, z).diff(x).subs(z, f(x, y))
Out[27]: 
⎛∂          ⎞│         
⎜──(A(x, z))⎟│         
⎝∂x         ⎠│z=f(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That certainly creates what I am looking for visually. The question is whether or not I can actually carry out the chain rule symbolically while one of the variables (z in the case you provided) is held constant.

Comment: The derivative wrt `x` in this example will treat `z` as constant. In sympy every derivative is a partial derivative.

Comment: I tried to take the derivative of this expression by setting this to an expression by running `expr = A(x, z).diff(x).subs(z, f(x, y))` and then running`expr.doit()` to see if it would apply the chain rule, but it did not. It just gave the original expression back to me. The result should have been what is seen in equation 6.1 on page 2 in the link provided. Am I perhaps doing something wrong?